# Wix IIS Version check launch condition not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Hi I am trying to add launch condition to check IIS Version installed is greater than 7 if not it should display compliance message.

```
 <PropertyRef Id="IISMAJORVERSION"/>
   <Condition Message="Install requires IIS 7 or higher">
    <![CDATA[IISMAJORVERSION AND (IISMAJORVERSION >= #7)]>
    </Condition>
```

Also tried IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" and IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" but
it is not showing condition message on the machines which doesn't have IIs installed. Please help.

Comment: Open your compiled MSI in Orca. Are there entries in the LaunchCondition table?

Answer (score 1):

As IISMAJORVERSION is a string we cannot perform greater than or lesser than. Hence I modified my condition to below.

```
<PropertyRef Id="IISMAJORVERSION"/>
 <Condition Message="Installer requires IIS 6 or 7 or higher versions installed on the machine.">
<![CDATA[(IISMAJORVERSION <> "") AND (IISMAJORVERSION <> "#1") AND (IISMAJORVERSION <> "#2") AND (IISMAJORVERSION <> "#3") AND (IISMAJORVERSION <> "#4") AND (IISMAJORVERSION <> "#5")]]>
</Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Check MSI***: Open your compiled MSI in Orca ([or an equivalent tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482546/129130) - see towards bottom). Are there entries in the **`LaunchCondition`** table? ***I can't see how that condition could compile*** - in its current form. You might have linked with old object files or something like that. Meaning that you current build is actually failing to produce a new MSI file, you are using an old one without noticing.

***Condition***: I think you have a mistake in the condition formatting, maybe try something like this:

```xml
<Condition Message="Install requires IIS 7 or higher">
     <![CDATA[IISMAJORVERSION AND (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7")]]>
</Condition>
```

Notice the double brackets at the end and the < and > characters at both ends and the quotes around #7. I didn't check the actual condition. Isn't it enough with the second part?

[Alternatively use an escape character as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52292742/129130).